# VS2010: How to use the prop snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, properties

Excuse my ignorance.  I just saw Scott Hanselman's video on MVC 3 where he typed prop, which I had not seen before.  I tried it but I am doing something wrong.  LOL

I type `prop` which expands to

```
public TYPE Type1 { get; set; }
```

and highlights TYPE.  I type the data type which replaces the word TYPE, hit tab to move to the Type1 placeholder and start typing, but it doesn't replace Type1, just types in front of it.

What's the correct way to move between TYPE and Type1 so that it highlights and replaces these placeholders as you type, and to move to the next line?

All the stuff I found on the Internet just said it creates this for you, but didn't say how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press Tab twice after replacing TYPE, thats will be delete word Type1.

Comment: That's it!  Thank you very much.  Now on to creating a ton of properties.

Comment: Super saver, Not sure why Microsoft doesn't make this more obvious in the intellisense!  Big Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Press `TAB` to expand the snippet, `TAB` to loop through all the placeholders, and `ENTER` to commit the snippet once finished.

Note: C# and HTML/ASP.NET/JScript snippets all behave approximately the same.  VB snippets behave slightly different in that pressing `ENTER` does not commit the snippet (which is very annoying IMHO).

Comment: Is there a way to commit the snippet in VB?

Answer (score 2):

The 'prop' snippet doesn't populate this way in Visual Studio 2010- the prop snippet only creates a manually editable template. you can, however, use Auto-Implemented Properties; this is (arguably) a better riff on the same concept:

-First, type:

*[Public | Private | Etc] Property MyPropName as [New] MyPropType [= DefaultVal]*

VS will (invisibly) implement standard Get/Set functionality automatically

To expand the Get/Set code, just go to the blank line following the property declaration, and type:

*G [Enter] | S [Enter]*

to generate explicit read-only get or write-only set code (respectively)

[SOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx#Y456)

Answer (score 1):

Just type prop then press TAB twice.  That's all.